# Scanning with Morena generates error: Failed to load twain_32.dll

Tags: citrix, twain, morena

I am working on a scan applet for browser. I use Morena 6.4.

Everything works on my local PC.

Sometimes this applet is started behind Citrix application server (4.5 version). Everything for image scanning is configured ok - some native applications can scan (this application uses TWAIN, like Morena).

When I try to scan with Morena, I get this error:

> SK.gnome.twain.TwainExcaption: Failed to load twain_32.dll (error=126)

Image of the error:
[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

According to your description, it seems be a permission issue, i.e. morena doesn't have enough permission to load twain_32.dll. What I used to verify it is to run the application as administrator, i.e. right click on the app, choose "run as admin".

In addition, please double check if the DLL (twain_32.dll) exists in C:\Windows. If not, you can [download](http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?twain_32) or copy one to this folder.

Hope my answer helps.

Comment: I would NOT recommend downloading dlls from any site that is not run by the developer of that file.